# Is a question too broad if there are multiple ways to back up a correct answer?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question is trying to get some clarification for why  [Are there in-universe reasons reason why Dany wouldn't start her conquest in Dorne?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131614/44294) would have been closed.

Here's the actual question:

> Any possible reason why Dany will not start her conquest of Westeros in Dorne?

To me that sounds like the OP is really asking a yes/no type of question.  "Should Dany start her conquest of Westeros in Dorne?"  While we can't answer whether or not Dany **will** start her conquest in Dorne, I believe it is possible to answer this question by presenting the currently known issues with a Dorne Invasion and letting the OP infer the answer based on that.

From my understanding, this question was put on hold as opinion based with the argument that multiple factors that lead to the same answer make a question unanswerable.

From my reading of [What are the good ways of avoiding a "promotes a pet theory" question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5150/44294), this should be considered on topic as asking for backup for a theory is considered on topic.

**Is this correct?  Is a question too broad if there are multiple lines of reasoning to get to the same answer?**

Comment: @amaranth the general situation with the specific question as an example. Since the VTC was based on that general argument.

Comment: There is a difference between "there are multiple ways to back up a correct answer?" and "there are no objective ways to back an answer at all, short of  guessing. And tangentially, your linked question isn't a good example of the former, since there are no clear "multiple ways to back an answer" in it. I still think your question should **not** be closed, but the reasons for it are unrelated to "multiple ways of backing".

Answer (score 3):

I would say no.

A question is too broad if there is (significantly) more than one answer.  Especially if the answers are a little speculative.  As stated in the close flag prompt:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

If there is a single answer then the number of ways to validate that answer is irrelevant.